# what would happen to the carry in binary base 8 addition?

Tags: binary, radix

What would happen if I added 2 binary numbers, 10000000 +  10000000 that were in base 8? 
What would happen to the carry?

Answer (score 0):

You can't be in binary (base 2) and base 8 at the same time.  I'm also having to assume you mean unsigned values from your sample values. Are you wondering about overflow here, truncation, something else?  In short, what are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Most modern CPUs have in their set of general-purpose flags, a carry flag (CF), that will contain the carry out of the high-order bit after an addition. So, in this specific case, assuming unsigned values 0b1000.0000, the sum will be 0b0000.0000 with the CF flag set, for a total "virtual" value of 0b1.0000.0000, which is the correct sum. Dealing with such overflows properly, however, is highly dependent on what the underlying algorithm is trying to do. In some cases, overflow is acceptable, in many it is not.